Run Node script with packages downloaded by npx
Suppose I have this script (script.js):
const semver require('semver');

semver.satisfies('123');

I'd like to run it through Node, but without installing semver on disk. I thought of npx:
npx -p semver -c "node script.js"

But Node does not find the semver package pulled by npx. Is there a way to tell Node to use the temporary environment created by npx?
I'm running on Windows, if that's relevant.
Edit :
I finally solved my problem using semver directly through npx, without intermediate script.
I seems that it's not possible to do what I was trying, although I'm still interested if there's a way.

If the script is part of a package that depends on semver and is properly defined as a script,  simply npx <name> will work.

@jonrsharpe that's not the case, but it may be the start of a solution. I could move my script in his own folder with his package.json

This looks like XY problem. Consider explaining your case, so a better solution could be suggested. From what I see the only way running script is related with npx is that the path to the installed temp package is exposed through path env. So you could exec "where semver"/"which semver" and calculate path to package from there
